# Atom Beauty can't find PHP

Tags: php, atom-editor

Usually I don't use tabs when I write code in PHP, because of that I wanted to install atom-beauty. So, I installed this plugin some time ago, but it can't run. I receive this output

```
Could not find 'php'. The program may not be installed.
See php installation instructions at https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify#beautifiers or go to http://php.net/manual/en/install.php
You can configure Atom Beautify with the absolute path to 'php' by setting 'Executable - PHP - Path' in the Atom Beautify package settings.
Your program is properly installed if running 'which php' in your Terminal returns an absolute path to the executable.
```

But I have already installed PHP, maybe I should set a path for them? I don't find any place where I can paste path to php. Or maybe I should install some php package? Already I have installed php and php-fpm in newest version and I use Arch Linux.

Comment: what do you get if you run `which php`?

Comment: I receive /usr/bin/php

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this entry on the github page:

[PHP in Atom Beauty](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/blob/v0.32.5/docs/options.md#php)

> PHP
>
> Important: This option is only configurable from within Atom Beautify's setting  panel.
>
> Type: object
>
> Description:
>
> Options for PHP executable.
>
> How to Configure
>
> You can open the Settings View by navigating to Edit > Preferences (Linux), Atom > Preferences (OS X), or File > Preferences (Windows).
>       Go into Packages and search for "Atom Beautify" package.
>       Find the option "PHP" and change it to your desired configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the php beautify option. Unless php embellishment is not urgent in my case it was not necessary to embellish language